# Css float: left; drops further on every item

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

scss

```
 ul {
     float: left;
 }
```

view

```
<% @project.columns.each do |col| %>
    <strong><h2><%= col.name %></h2></strong>
    <ul id='tasks_<%= col.name %>' data-update-url='<%= sort_project_tasks_url(@project) %>'>
    <% col.tasks.sort_by { |t| t.priority }.each do |task| %>

        <li id="task_<%= task.id %>">
             <%= task.name %>| <%= task.column.name %> | <%= task.priority %>
        </li>

    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

The problem: I try to display all my unordered lists parallelly. My scss places them side by side, but every next list drops one line below from previous one. I checked if my navbar, debug partial or Bootstrap cause this. Also, checked if I could randomly generate extra new line in view loops or if list values could contain it.

Falling down screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/htOfm.png (Test list is empty)
Weird that if I apply float: left; on list elements they don't drop down
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLrGp.png

Tried two browsers: Chromium browser (Version 57.0.2987.98) and Firefox 53.0 (64-bit)

UPD: Rendered html part

```
<h1>Tasks:</h1>

<strong><h2>dev</h2></strong>
<ul id="tasks_dev" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks/sort">

  <li id="task_1">
    Do it| dev | 0
  </li>


  <li id="task_3">
    quas et autem| dev | 1
  </li>


  <li id="task_6">
    autem vel est| dev | 4
  </li>


  <li id="task_8">
    sunt velit ut| dev | 6
  </li>


  <li id="task_14">
    itaque quia est| dev | 12
  </li>


  <li id="task_16">
    illum qui provident| dev | 14
  </li>


  <li id="task_17">
    accusamus voluptas pariatur| dev | 15
  </li>


  <li id="task_20">
    dolorum voluptate ipsa| dev | 18
  </li>
```

```
<strong><h2>done</h2></strong>

<ul id="tasks_done" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks/sort">

  <li id="task_2">
    quaerat et maiores| done | 0
  </li>


  <li id="task_4">
    autem doloremque doloribus| done | 2
  </li>


  <li id="task_11">
    voluptates quod sunt| done | 9
  </li>


  <li id="task_12">
    aliquam eum et| done | 10
  </li>


  <li id="task_13">
    officiis animi excepturi| done | 11
  </li>


  <li id="task_15">
    delectus dignissimos beatae| done | 13
  </li>


  <li id="task_18">
    ullam dolorum aut| done | 16
  </li>


  <li id="task_19">
    aut qui magni| done | 17
  </li>
```

```
 <strong><h2>production</h2></strong>

<ul id="tasks_production" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks/sort">

  <li id="task_5">
    eos tempora consequatur| production | 3
  </li>


  <li id="task_7">
    aperiam rem et| production | 5
  </li>


  <li id="task_9">
    et omnis explicabo| production | 7
  </li>


  <li id="task_10">
    consequatur iusto qui| production | 8
  </li>


  <li id="task_21">
    corrupti doloremque quod| production | 19
  </li>
```

```
<strong><h2>test</h2></strong>

<ul id="tasks_test" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks/sort">
</ul>
```

Had to add new lines after  titles so stackoverflow will recognize it as part of code, orginal html didn't have any.

Comment: Hi, the html/css you provided doesn't reproduce the issue. Please give us the minimal amount of rendered html and css needed to reproduce the problem in your screenshots.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Hello. Added rendered html snippets. Also, here's rendered version on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DmitriyS/qjoe3et9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Enclose each list in a div and use float:left on div. Don't forget to use clear:both after lists.

```css
.abc {
  float: left;
}
#clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:3000/">Agile-board</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="http://localhost:3000/projects/1#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/projects/1#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/projects/1#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/projects/1#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="http://localhost:3000/logout">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<h1>Tasks:</h1>
<div class="abc">
  <strong><h2>dev</h2></strong>
  <ul id="tasks_dev" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks/sort">
    <li id="task_1">
      Do it| dev | 0
    </li>
    <li id="task_3">
      quas et autem| dev | 1
    </li>
    <li id="task_6">
      autem vel est| dev | 4
    </li>
    <li id="task_8">
      sunt velit ut| dev | 6
    </li>
    <li id="task_14">
      itaque quia est| dev | 12
    </li>
    <li id="task_16">
      illum qui provident| dev | 14
    </li>
    <li id="task_17">
      accusamus voluptas pariatur| dev | 15
    </li>
    <li id="task_20">
      dolorum voluptate ipsa| dev | 18
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <strong><h2>done</h2></strong>
  <ul id="tasks_done" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks/sort">
    <li id="task_2">
      quaerat et maiores| done | 0
    </li>
    <li id="task_4">
      autem doloremque doloribus| done | 2
    </li>
    <li id="task_11">
      voluptates quod sunt| done | 9
    </li>
    <li id="task_12">
      aliquam eum et| done | 10
    </li>
    <li id="task_13">
      officiis animi excepturi| done | 11
    </li>
    <li id="task_15">
      delectus dignissimos beatae| done | 13
    </li>
    <li id="task_18">
      ullam dolorum aut| done | 16
    </li>
    <li id="task_19">
      aut qui magni| done | 17
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <strong><h2>production</h2></strong>
  <ul id="tasks_production" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks/sort">
    <li id="task_5">
      eos tempora consequatur| production | 3
    </li>
    <li id="task_7">
      aperiam rem et| production | 5
    </li>
    <li id="task_9">
      et omnis explicabo| production | 7
    </li>
    <li id="task_10">
      consequatur iusto qui| production | 8
    </li>
    <li id="task_21">
      corrupti doloremque quod| production | 19
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <strong><h2>test</h2></strong>
  <ul id="tasks_test" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks/sort">
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
<br>
<br>
<h3>Crew:</h3>
<br> Dmitriy Spivakov(dmitriy.spiv@gmail.com) : RoR junior |
<a href="http://localhost:3000/user_roles/1/edit">Edit role</a> |
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="http://localhost:3000/user_roles/1">Delete</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:3000/projects/1/user_roles/new">Add coworker</a>
<pre class="debug_dump">--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  controller: projects
  action: show
  id: '1'
permitted: false
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens as the ul has no width parameter. Try:

```
ul {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```